# Postgres exception in C#

Tags: c#, visual-studio, postgresql

I am trying to connect a PostgreSQL database to a C# console app. This is my code:

```
static void Main(string[] args)
{
    string connstring = String.Format("Server=localhost;Port=5432;" +
                    "User Id=postgres;Password=admin;Database=mydb;");
    NpgsqlConnection conn = new NpgsqlConnection(connstring);
    conn.Open();

    string sql = string.Format("CREATE TABLE public.stvari2 ime text, broj smallint, id integer)");
    NpgsqlCommand cmd = new NpgsqlCommand(sql, conn);
    cmd.ExecuteNonQuery();
}
```

I literally copied the the reverse-engineered SQL query from Postgres, so I doubt that that's the problem. Anyhow, when I run it I get an exception:

> An unhandled exception of type 'Npgsql.PostgresException' occurred in Npgsql.dll

at the last line (executeNonQuery).
Any ideas?

Answer (score 3):

Looking at your SQL string -- are you missing a ( ?

```
string sql = string.Format("CREATE TABLE public.stvari2 ime text, broj smallint, id integer)");
```

In here dont you need another (    -->  public.stvari2( ime

```
string sql = string.Format("CREATE TABLE public.stvari2( ime text, broj smallint, id integer)");
```

Answer (score 0):

try like this it will work

```
 static void Main(string[] args)
        {

            String connections = "Server=192.168.1.163;Port=5432;Database=postgres;User Id=postgres;Password=root;";
            NpgsqlConnection connection = new NpgsqlConnection();
            connection.ConnectionString = connections;
            connection.Open();

            try
            {
                NpgsqlCommand cmd = new NpgsqlCommand();
                cmd.Connection = connection;
                cmd.CommandText = "INSERT INTO sector(name,address,designition,description,auto_id) values ('vinoth','chennai','sds','wdewd','123')";
                cmd.CommandType = CommandType.Text;
                cmd.ExecuteNonQuery();                                                        
                cmd.Dispose();

            }
            catch (Exception e)
            {
                e.ToString();
            }
}
```